# issue with load more results in php ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am following MVC structure on PHP which I have downloaded from [github](https://github.com/panique/php-mvc) which is very helpful for me.

Now I have implemented Ajax functionality for lazy loading to load more post on user click(load more).

I have implemented on this structure and it working perfect but I am getting small issue. The issue is when there is no records available its still show me **Load more content** and then display **No More Content to Load**

I tried to solve this issue but i can't solved that's why I came here.

**My code works:**

**index.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('.more_button').live("click", function () {
        var getId = $(this).attr("id");
        if (getId) {
            $("#load_more_" + getId).html('<img src="<?php echo URL; ?>public/img/load_img.gif" style="padding:10px 0 0 100px;"/>');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo URL; ?>home/loadSong",
                data: "getLastContentId=" + getId,
                cache: false,
                success: function (html) {
                    $("ul#load_more_ctnt").append(html);
                    $("#load_more_" + getId).remove();
                }
            });
        } else {
            $(".more_tab").html("<div class='all_loaded'>No More Content to Load</div>");
        }
        return false;
    });
});
</script>

<div class='main_div'>
    <ul class="load_content" id="load_more_ctnt">
        <?php foreach ($songs as $song) { $id = $song->id; ?>
            <li> <a href="#"><?php if (isset($song->artist)) echo $song->artist; ?></a> </li>
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
    <div class="more_div">
        <a href="#">
            <div id="load_more_<?php echo $id; ?>" class="more_tab">
                <div class="more_button" id="<?php echo $id; ?>">Load More Content</div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**home.php (controller)**

```
public function loadSong() {

        if(isset($_POST['getLastContentId'])) {
            // load model, perform an action on the model
            $getLastContentId=$_POST['getLastContentId'];
            $songs_model = $this->loadModel('HomeModel');
            $songs_model->loadmoreSong($getLastContentId);
        }
    }
```

**homemodel.php (model)**

```
public function loadmoreSong($getLastContentId) {       

        if(isset($_POST['getLastContentId'])) {

            $getLastContentId=$_POST['getLastContentId'];

            $sql = "select id, artist, track, link from song WHERE id <".$getLastContentId." ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10";
            $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $query->execute();
            $count = $query->fetchAll();

            if($count>0) {
                $id = "";
                for($i=0; $i<count($count); $i++){
                    $id = $count[$i]->id;
                    $message = $count[$i]->artist;
                ?>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><?php echo $message; ?></a>
                    </li>

                <?php
                    }
                ?>

                <a href="#">
                    <div id="load_more_<?php echo $id; ?>" class="more_tab">
                        <div id="<?php echo $id; ?>" class="more_button">Load More Content</div>
                    </div>
                </a>

            <?php
                }
            }
    }
```

My live demo link: [Load More Demo](http://mananpatel.in/project/load-more/)

I hope you understand my question. Need your help to fix this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: You would need to read the total count of results and show or no show the .more_div part accordingly.

Comment: Please provide the else statement in the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just edit this piece of code:

```
<a href="#">
 <div id="load_more_<?php echo $id; ?>" class="more_tab">
 <div id="<?php echo $id; ?>" class="more_button">Load More Content</div>
 </div>
</a>
```

To this:

```
<?php    
if($id!=""){
?>
<a href="#">
 <div id="load_more_<?php echo $id; ?>" class="more_tab">
 <div id="<?php echo $id; ?>" class="more_button">Load More Content</div>
 </div>
</a>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add **SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS** to your SELECT query like:

```
select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS id, artist, tra....
```

Then check the found rows with:

```
SELECT FOUND_ROWS()
```

Store the result in a var **$found_rows**.

Then, at the end of *homemodel.php* you'll have:

```
if ( $count < $found_rows ) {
    ?>
            <a href="#">
                <div id="load_more_<?php echo $id; ?>" class="more_tab">
                    <div id="<?php echo $id; ?>" class="more_button">Load More Content</div>
                </div>
            </a>
    <?php
} else {
    ?>
            <a href="#">
                <div id="load_more_<?php echo $id; ?>" class="more_tab">
                     <div class='all_loaded'>No More Content to Load</div>
                </div>
            </a>
    <?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
if($count > 0)
```

to:

```
if($count)
```

Comment: That changes nothing, except extra internal casting to bool.

Comment: actually yes it does change everything, because when you are checking if array is greater than scalar it will always return true

Comment: nice one spotting it. you tell him :)